# Hibernate Merge vs. Update on traditional REST API

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I understand the a substantial benefit of using merge when updating an object is that a user can take time between database transactions without keeping the resources open, and then just open a transaction again when it's time to persist the changed object.

However, in a traditional web application, is merge still needed as much? For instance, all the data that the user is updating on the object will be passed through with request form data. Therefore, it seems kind of useless to open a connection to grab an object, detach the object from the entity manager (cache), invoke the changes on the detached object, then open up another entity manager just to merge the changed object back into the database and close the transaction.

It's not like the user is spending an unknown amount of time in between the transaction opening and closing it. It all should happen in 'one fell swoop' because the request parameters are being invoked inside the function that manages the transaction.

What is the advantage in this case of using merge?

For instance, let's say we have a Dog object. A user sends a request to change the name and age of the dog. This request goes through the controller and service layer to hit my Dog repository/persistence layer. Here, an entity manager establishes the beginning of a transaction, grabs the Dog object from the database, loads it into cache, and utilizes automatic dirty checking to change the Dog object's name and age. Then the transaction commits and closes after the persist method is called on the Dog object.

Is there a problem doing this? Why would I NOT do this, as opposed to:

Entity manager is created, Dog object is collected into cache, entity manager is closed. Detached Dog object's name and age fields are changed. New entity manager is created, and updated Dog object is merged in and transaction is closed. To me this seems like more of a waste of resources because we have to create two connections to the database. I can understand if this were in a case where a traditional stateless request/response web application weren't being used, and the client had more time between the transaction to mess around.

However, in a stateless request/response cycle, once the request is sent, it's sent, and the time between a queried Dog object's collection into cache and that same object being returned to the database isn't varied by how long a client/user takes to make a decision. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it depends on the size of the  change set (nearly the entire entity, relations vs. single fields) and how the data representation handled via request / response looks like (json, xml or other kind of key-value pairs). But in general you are totally right, just use one transaction / connection to update an entity with the values of the request. Nevertheless there is not black  or white and it may be useful to go a different way in some cases.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. In a way, you could think of it as a "merge between controllers" in a RESTful paradigm. The user commits one transaction to GET the data. That stateless transaction is then closed and the data is displayed on the user's device. When the user decides to update that data, in a RESTful scenario, they will be doing so within a different controller, which will not necessarily invoke a second entity manager, but will most likely use the same singleton entity manager to open and close another transaction on the new data the client wishes to update.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Yeah, that's exactly what I mean. GET request (first transaction) -> user's think time -> POST / PUT request (second transaction)

Answer (score 2):

The real advantage of `merge` [entity state transition](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/) is when you reuse a detached entity across multiple web requests.

For instance, the first read-only requests loads the entity which, after the transaction is ended and the Persistence Context is closed, is saved in the current `HttpSession`.

The use decides what modifications to apply to the currently loaded entity, so in the following Http request which triggers a read-write transaction, the user can apply the changes onto the previously fetched entity.

There are two advantages to this approach:

1. You execute only one `SELECT` query to load the entity.
2. The merged entity will be attached to the currently running Persistence Context, hence every modification is automatically detected by the [dirty checking mechanism](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/).
3. You make sure that, in case you also enable [optimistic locking](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/), you prevent [lost updates](https://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/).

That's why `merge` is useful.

### Update

> The user can simply click the 'update' button on the view, and that data will be sent in a stateless manner.

In this case, you can pass the entity version back and forth in a stateless manner. The second transaction will have to fetch the entity and apply the previous version along with all other changes.

This way, you can make sure you won't lose updates. Without using the load-time version, you can risk a lost update phenomenon.

Comment: Vlad, thanks. But question: In the everyday RESTful paradigm, the user technically decides what modifications to apply to the currently loaded entity only AFTER that entity has been sent as data to the view layer. In a properly designed RESTful api, the update controller will have been separate from the read controller method. Therefore, there is no for a merge of the original data to a second entity manager when the user decides to update the data, b/c the data is stateless. The user can simply click the 'update' button on the view, and that data will be sent in a stateless manner. True?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think it's important to make the distinction that lost updates is not a problem for all applications. An application where users can only update entities that they have permissions over (Twitter tweets, Youtube comments, etc) will not have to deal with optimistic or pessimistic locking. In common cases like these, multiple users can constantly add, remove, and update their own data to an entity (a comment list for example) without lost update issues.

Comment: In those cases, you won't use the version and apply new changes directly onto a freshly loaded entity. No need for any merging, just typical managed entity dirty checking.

Comment: I would even go as far as to advise against locking in an application where multiple users are encouraged to update entities freely. If 30 users send an update request at the same time on a single entity, they will each open a transaction, grab the current 'version' of the entity, and submit an update only to find 29 of them have received errors due to having the wrong version. On the other hand if left unlocked, they will each open a single transaction, update the entity within the transaction, and dirty checking will cause the last update to persist, no errors for anyone.

Comment: That's how CQRS works. The transaction log is moved upfront,but then you accept anything, hence the data integrity validation have to run after you accepted user requests. So, it's up to the app requirements to figure out which is the best approach.

Comment: I think both of you are right. If you have a state and keep the entity around the merge can really be useful. On the other hand - if your requests don't rely on a serverside state - applying the  changes onto a fresh entity is common. So as I said, no black or white. :)